# GXT - Auto height in Info popup

Tags: extjs, popup, gxt

I am using class com.extjs.gxt.ui.client.widget.Info for showing popup messages. I need to show messages of different height, so popup element should change its height automatically.
For first look, it is possible - Info has method setAutoHeight, inherited from BoxComponent, but I can't get instance of Info - it has only static methods for showing.
I tried to set listener in InfoConfig - but it seems that it's ignored.
Are there any ways to set auto height for this component?